# How can I configure my hibernate to save entitys

Tags: java, hibernate

I have 5 tables every table has relation one to many with the next table 
Project_t -> project_level1_t -> project_level2_t -> project_level3_t -> project_level4_t 
I want to user hibernate with these tables

```
CREATE TABLE project_t
(
  projectid serial NOT NULL,
  address1 character varying(128),
  postcode character varying(7),
  city character varying(64),
  level_four_name character varying(128),
  CONSTRAINT project_t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (projectid),
  CONSTRAINT projectcode_unique UNIQUE (projectcode)
)
```

And project_level1_t

```
CREATE TABLE project_level1_t
(
  projectlevel1id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('project_level1_t_projectlevel1pk_seq'::regclass),
  levelname character varying(256),
  projectid integer,
  CONSTRAINT project_level1_t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (projectlevel1id),
  CONSTRAINT project_level1_t_project_t_fkey FOREIGN KEY (projectid)
      REFERENCES project_t (projectid) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

And project_level2_t

```
CREATE TABLE project_level2_t
(
  projectlevel2id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('project_level2_t_projectlevel2_seq'::regclass),
  levelname character varying(256),
  projectlevel1id integer,
  CONSTRAINT project_level2_t_pkey PRIMARY KEY (projectlevel2id),
  CONSTRAINT project_level2_t_projec_level_1_fkey FOREIGN KEY (projectlevel1id)
      REFERENCES project_level1_t (projectlevel1id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

And this is the Repository files

```
   package ma.eurnet.mp.tables.model;

    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

    @JsonAutoDetect
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "project_t")
    public class ProjectRepository implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ProjectRepository() {
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "projectid")
        private Long projectId;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="project")
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<ProjectLevel1Repository> projectlevel1 = new ArrayList<ProjectLevel1Repository>();

        public Long getProjectId() {
            return projectId;
        }

        public void setProjectId(Long projectId) {
            this.projectId = projectId;
        }

        public List<ProjectLevel1Repository> getProjectlevel1() {
            return projectlevel1;
        }

        public void setProjectlevel1(List<ProjectLevel1Repository> projectlevel1) {
            this.projectlevel1 = projectlevel1;
        }
```

and

```
 package ma.eurnet.mp.tables.model;

    @JsonAutoDetect
    @Entity
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "projectLevel1Sequence", sequenceName = "project_level1_t_projectlevel1pk_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Table(name="project_level1_t")
    public class ProjectLevel1Repository implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ProjectLevel1Repository() {
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "projectLevel1Sequence")
        @Column(name = "projectlevel1id")
        private Long projectLevel1Id;    

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="projectid", referencedColumnName = "projectid")
        @JsonIgnore
        private ProjectRepository project;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="projectlevel1id")
        @JsonIgnore
        private List<ProjectLevel2Repository> projectlevel2 = new ArrayList<ProjectLevel2Repository>();

        public List<ProjectLevel2Repository> getProjectlevel2() {
            return projectlevel2;
        }

        public Long getProjectLevel1Id() {
            return projectLevel1Id;
        }


        public void setProjectLevel1Id(Long projectLevel1Id) {
            this.projectLevel1Id = projectLevel1Id;
        }


        public ProjectRepository getProject() {
            return project;
        }


        public void setProject(ProjectRepository project) {
            this.project = project;
        }




    }
```

And

```
package ma.eurnet.mp.tables.model;

import java.io.Serializable;


@JsonAutoDetect
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "projectLevel2Sequence", sequenceName = "project_level2_t_projectlevel2_seq", allocationSize = 1)
@Table(name="project_level2_t")
public class ProjectLevel2Repository implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ProjectLevel2Repository() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "projectLevel2Sequence")
    @Column(name = "projectlevel2id")
    private Long projectLevel2Id;

    @Column(name = "levelname")
    private String levelName;


    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "creation_date")
    private String creationDate;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="projectlevel1id", referencedColumnName = "projectlevel1id")
    @JsonIgnore
    private ProjectLevel1Repository projectlevel1id;

    public Long getProjectLevel2Id() {
        return projectLevel2Id;
    }


    public void setProjectLevel2Id(Long projectLevel2Id) {
        this.projectLevel2Id = projectLevel2Id;
    }


    public String getLevelName() {
        return levelName;
    }


    public void setLevelName(String levelName) {
        this.levelName = levelName;
    }


    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }


    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }


    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }


    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }


    public ProjectRepository getProjectlevel1id() {
        return projectlevel1id;
    }


    public void setProjectlevel1id(ProjectRepository projectlevel1id) {
        this.projectlevel1id = projectlevel1id;
    }



}
```

I want to save each entity by himself so if run this code

```
ProjectRepository projectRepository =  projectService.getProjectById(Long.parseLong(projectId));

ProjectLevel1Repository projectLevel1Repository = new ProjectLevel1Repository();
projectLevel1Repository.setProject(projectRepository);
projectLevel1Repository.setLevelName(level1Name);

projectLevel1Service.saveOrUpdateRepository(projectLevel1Repository);

ProjectLevel2Repository projectLevel2Repository = new ProjectLevel2Repository();
projectLevel2Repository.setLevelName("Test Level 2");
projectLevel2Repository.setProjectlevel1id(projectLevel1Repository);

projectLevel2Service.saveOrUpdateRepository(projectLevel2Repository);
```

I want to save one projectLevel1 and one projectLevel2 but what is happening now two projectLevel1 save with one projectLevel2

Comment: Why are you naming your entity classes repositories? Entity class name should resemble name of the object (like db table does). Adding `Repository` is ok for implementing crud repository for your entity.

Comment: it is an old code and I need to update it and I will fix that problem later

Comment: You might want to show the code for your `services` and please add new code if you've updated it because reading the word `repository` for something which is an `entity` is really hurtful.